# How can I find all indices of a value in a multidimensional array?

Tags: python

How can I write a function that will return all indices of a specific value inside a function?

For example:

```
arr = ["foo", ["foo", "foo", [1, "foo"]], "foo"]
getAllIndicesRecursively("foo", arr)
```

This should return all indices of "foo", which are: `[[0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,2,1],[2]]`.

Comment: @icedwater I've tried dozens of Google search queries for this question, and I've found no relevant results so far.

Comment: OK, but what have you tried /implementing/ so far?

Comment: I don't see how your asserted result matches the example list

Comment: Why is everyone voting to close my question? Is this considered a bad question for some reason? (I'm so frustrated that I'm actually considering suicide now - I'm getting tired of being criticized for my lack of expertise with Python.)

Comment: @AndersonGreen We're not here to write code for you. We're here to help people if they're stuck with their code. And really, if you're considering suicide, I do hope you don't continue to and maybe you should go and see someone

Comment: Why is everyone voting to close my question? Is this considered a bad question for some reason? I haven't tried to answer my own question yet, but I still think it's a potentially useful question (and therefore it shouldn't be closed).

Comment: @Haidro I'm not asking anyone to do anything for me: I'm only asking for advice on where to start.

Comment: `import itertools; getAllIndicesRecursively = lambda y, xs, idx=[]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([idx + [i]] if x == y else getAllIndicesRecursively(y, x, idx + [i]) if isinstance(x, list) else [] for i, x in enumerate(xs)))`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[[0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [2]]`? Start with the terminal case. ie a non-nested list. That's about half the work

Comment: @falsetru Maybe you should re-post this as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @AndersonGreen, I commented it when this question was closed. I think it is not need to be posted as answer, because it is very similar to perreal's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly the output you imagine, but this one preserves the nested structure of lists:

```
def getAllIndicesRecursively(s, l):
    r = []
    for i, v in enumerate(l):
        if isinstance(v, list):
            r += [ getAllIndicesRecursively(s, v) ]
        elif v == s: r += [ i ]
    return r

arr = ["foo", ["foo", "foo", [1, "foo"]], "foo"]
getAllIndicesRecursively("foo", arr)
```

*Output:*

```
[0, [0, 1, [1]], 2]
```

And this gives the output you describe:

```
def getAllIndicesRecursively(s, l, agg=[], path=[]):
    for i, v in enumerate(l):
        if isinstance(v, list):
            getAllIndicesRecursively(s, v, agg, path + [ i ] )
        elif v == s: agg += [ path + [ i ] ]
    return agg
```

*Output:*

```
[[0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [2]]
```

Comment: You should probably save a copy of this answer - I'm afraid that my question is going to be deleted in the future since it got so many downvotes. (I still don't understand why my question was closed as off-topic).

Comment: @AndersonGreen, it is because your question makes it seem like you didn't try to solve it yourself.

Comment: How does this diminish the question's potential usefulness?